# How to replace variable string with another variable string using sed

Tags: bash, shell, sed

So I'm trying to replace a line content in a file with multiple lines but I can't get it to work. Here's the details:

Text File: `/home/user1/file1.txt`

File content:

```
The quick brown fox
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy fat dog
Little brown and the lazy fat dog
Lazy dog and the fat lion
```

string1=`"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy fat dog"`

string2=`"The quick little black fox jumps over the lazy fat dog
The quick big brown fox jumps over the lazy fat dog
The lazy little brown fox jumps over the lazy fat dog"`

Shell script file: `/home/user1/replace_me.sh`

So if I run the shell script file with the below `sid command`, the file content would be changed to:

```
The quick brown fox
The quick little black fox jumps over the lazy fat dog
The quick big brown fox jumps over the lazy fat dog
The lazy little brown fox jumps over the lazy fat dog 
Little brown and the lazy fat dog 
Lazy dog and the fat lion
```

I used [How to replace a variable with another variable using sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55479262/how-to-replace-a-variable-with-another-variable-using-sed) and [Replace a word with multiple lines using sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10107459/replace-a-word-with-multiple-lines-using-sed) as references:

These are the commands I tried with no luck :(

`sed -i "s/$string1/$string2/" /home/user1/file1.txt`

`sed -i "/${string1}/{s/^.*/${string2}/" /home/user1/file1.txt`

Below is the shell script file content:

```
#!/bin/bash

string1="The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy fat dog"

string2="The quick little black fox jumps over the lazy fat dog
The quick big brown fox jumps over the lazy fat dog
The lazy little brown fox jumps over the lazy fat dog"

sed -i "s/$string1/$string2/" /home/user1/file1.txt

#sed -i "/${string1}/{s/^.*/${string2}/" /home/user1/file1.txt
```

Comment: There should be no `/` before `s` command, `sed -i "s/$string1/$string2/" /home/user1/file1.txt`

Comment: Though `sed` is generally a poor choice of tools for this job -- one needs to do escaping or else not all characters will work correctly (`/`, in the case of Wiktor's example above). See [BashFAQ #21](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/021), and particularly the definition of `gsub_literal` therein, for tools that do it better. (There's also a `perl`-based alternative described in that same page).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, apologies, that was a typo.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I just added the `none` as per your advice to make the block a literal data. Thanks.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy `perl` based alternative is not an option at the moment as we don't have it on all our linux servers and we don't allow it. This is something that I need to replace the content of a file on all our linux servers.

Comment: `gsub_literal` is built on `awk`. Being POSIX-defined, that's more likely to be present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> replace a line content in a file with multiple lines

In `sed` commands are *delimetered* with a newline. So when `sed` sees `s/blabla/blabla<newline>` is parses that part as a full command and exits with a missing closing `/`.

You can substitute each newline in the replacement string for two characters `\n`, which can be then substituted by `sed` for a newline once again.

```
string2=${string2//$'\n'/\\n}
sed "s/$string1/$string2/"
```

Note that `sed` parses first part of `s` command as a regex and in replacement string some strings (`\1` `&` `\L` `\U` etc.) are also parsed specially.

This will only work if there are no newlines in `string1`. With GNU `sed` you can get away with newlines in `string1` by using `-z` option, that will cause to parse the input as zero terminated strings.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
echo "$string2" | sed "s/$string1/cat -/e" file
```

This uses the `e` flag in the substitution command to send `$string2` to stdout using the stdin from the echoed pipe.

It should be noted `$string1` must be a single line and not contain any meta characters. If `$string1` does contains special characters, this might work in bash:

```
echo "$string2" |
sed 's/'"$(<<<"$string3" sed 's/[][^$.*&\/]/\\&/g')"'/cat -/e' file
```

This escapes any meta characters in `$string1` which then becomes the LHS of the substitution regexp.